# Curse of dimensionality with language models

Tags: distributions, text-mining, natural-language, degrees-of-freedom, language-models

In the seminal paper [A Neural Probabilistic Language Model](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/BengioDVJ03.pdf), Yoshua Bengio and his colleagues make the following point:

> If one wants to model the joint probability distribution of 10
>   consecutive words in a natural language with a vocabulary $V$ of size
>   $100,000$, there are potentially $100,000^{10}-1$ free parameters.

I guess it's related to degrees of freedom and joint distributions but I just can't get my hands on the exact formula that was used here to come up with $100,000^{10}-1$.

Comment: $100000$ is probably an estimate of the total number of words in the language.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen `1e5` is the size of the vocabulary, so yes, `1e5` is the total number of unique words in the language, no problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate $100 000^{10}-1$ comes from assuming a discrete model for the $10$ consecutive words, without any simplifications or restrictions, thus using all interactions up to and including order $10$.

It is not important that the words are consecutive, we would get the same count for any ten specified word positions. For each position, it can be any of the $100000$ words, so we need that number of probabilities. So you can build up a cube in $10$-space, wity each dimension cut up in $100000$ boxes. Taking all the combinations, that give $100000^{10}$ boxes, each box giving on possible $10$-word sequence, such as " am I writing now holy blue crap green integrated ideas", which would be a sequence of fairly low probability. Then subtract $1$ to account for the fact that the probabilities must sum to one!

In practice, a fairly high number of the probabilities would be zero, because they correspond to non-grammatical utterings.

Comment: please elaborate. Is the fact that words are consecutive important? How does joint distributions and degrees of freedom come into play? What is the formula that is used?

Comment: Many thanks for elaborating. In other words, $100,000^{10}$ gives all the possible 10-element combinations from the vocabulary of size $100,000$. This number is huge but still finite since we're in the discrete case. And estimating the joint probability mass function of a specific 10-word sequence comes down to assigning a probability (probabilities=parameters here I assume) to each portion of that huge but finite discrete sample space. Is that correct? Also, sorry if I'm being dumb but I still don't get why subtracting 1 ensures that the probabilities will sum to one.

Comment: subtracting one does not by itself secure that the probabilities will sum to one, but it takes care of that restriction . After freely choosing the $100000^{10}-1$ probabilities, you can calculate the last one!